# how can I subtract a method value from another method value in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've being trying to subtract a method value from another method value but it gives me a an error even when I use variables.

```
from tkinter import *
statistics = Tk()
screenwidth = statistics.winfo_screenwidth
windowwidth = statistics.winfo_width
distance = screenwidth - windowwidth
statistics.geometry(+distance+'0')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to subtract two functions. You want to subtract the results of calling the functions. Try this:

```py
from Tkinter import *
statistics = Tk()
screenwidth = statistics.winfo_screenwidth()
windowwidth = statistics.winfo_width()
distance = screenwidth - windowwidth
statistics.geometry('+%s+0' % distance)
```

Comment: is there any other way of getting the window in the top right corner of any computer.